# Add rule to ingress ngnix with query parameters in service

Tags: java, kubernetes, query-string, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Good morning, I currently have a microservice developed in java that has the following url made up of queryParameters:

```
https://localhost:8080/accountManagement/v4/partyAccount?nationalIdType=CI&nationalId=7315412&x-correlator=12345678
```

Now I have to expose said microservice in Kubernetes through an nginx-ingress, however, I have the question of how I am going to apply the rule for this case, since it is the first time that I work with a case like this

It must be something like this, but I have doubts:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-develop
  namespace: develop
  annotations: 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "20"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-dev
  tls: 
    - secretName: srvdevma1-ssl
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /accountManagement/v4/partyAccount?{*}
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: find-customer-accounts-list-by-doc-id
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Is this how I am proposing it or is something else missing?

Comment: you dont need regex part. requests starts with /accountManagement/v4/partyAccount redirected to pods as it is. then in application side you can process query params.